# How do I access instance variables inside an instance method called from an instance method at the same level

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an IBAction instance method that is connected to a slider, and displays the slider value in a Text Field that has the name datacellR1.  A copy of the code is below, followed by a question.  Both methods are in the @implementation section of the View2Controller.m file.

```
- (IBAction)slider1Change:(id)sender 
{

    float pctVal1 = [slider1 floatValue];  // this works
    [datacellR1 setFloatValue:pctVal1];         

   [View2Controller CalculateUpdatedTotal ]; // This method needs to work with the datacellR1 contents, but I can’t access it.


}



-(void)CalculateUpdatedTotal  
{  

    // -------- do some work with datacellR1 ----
    // This function fails with an error

    float newValue = [datacellR1 floatValue];

    //some other code goes here   

}
```

The error in slider1Change is that CalculateUpdatedTotal method is not found.  If I change CalculateUpdatedTotal from an instance method to a class method, the error is that the Instance variable datacellR1 accessed in a class method.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CalculateUpdatedTotal`, as written, is also an instance method. Therefore, to invoke it, you should pass the message to `self`, not the class (`View2Controller`):

```
[self CalculateUpdatedTotal];
```

By the way, it's conventional to begin method names in Objective-C with a lower-case letter.